# ECSlidingViewController - How do you know when the menu has been shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am integrating `[ECSlidingViewController]`, which I found on [github](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController), in my app and I want to know if there is a property which tells me if the menu has been shown or not. I will be using this to control the functionality of the menu button, as a toggle to hide and show the menu. Is there any such property?

Comment: I set up a function which returns a "menuShown" BOOL based on the current frame of the topViewController's view. So I got it to work. Couldn't find anything in the documentation though.

Comment: Yeah. I looked through the source quickly, and saw no such property. Frankly I'm surprised the developer of ECSlidingViewController left such a thing out the project. But whatever, glad you found a workaround. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same issue, i'm sure there is a better way but I just did:

```
- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = self.slidingViewController;
    if (slidingViewController.currentTopViewPosition == ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight) {
        [slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [slidingViewController anchorTopViewToRightAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the right method, based on the provided documentation, though mine works too even though its a workaround. I will accept this as the right answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the right approach would be to use the [Anchored Top Views Gestures](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/wiki/Gestures-Guide) in order to control how the Top View behaves while it is anchored to the side.

A common solution to create a toggle for showing and hiding the menu would be:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewAnchoredGesture = ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGesturePanning | ECSlidingViewControllerAnchoredGestureTapping;
```

Allowing the user to hide the menu using the Tap or the Pan gestures.